# How to account for company restructuring when determining closed won credit?

Tags: ownership, business-logic

This is more of an admin-related question, but can't seem to find answers anywhere else. Here's my issue:

Assume you have sales rep A who is managed by sales manager 1. Sales rep A sells, generates leads, wins some opportunities. Sales manager 1 when reporting sees all of the numbers for her/ his sales reps as it rolls up nicely. Now 6 months into your fiscal year, sales rep A is changed to Sales manager 2. With that change, any leads created up until that point, deals won etc, are now automatically displaying under sales manager 2 while sales manager 1 is left with nothing.

The business would like to be able to include past leads created, opps won, etc. to stay with sales manager 1 and only newly created leads, won opps etc to be listed under sales manager 2. The ownership for opportunities has not changed, they are still with sales rep A. So give the sales manager credit who was managing the sales rep at the time of lead creation, winning an opportunity or other stage changes.

Seems like it would be a very common business problem but I have not been able to find a simple way to get this accomplished. How would you solve this challenge? (Declarative would be preferred and would like to stay away from Analytic snapshots).

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by creating a workflow that captures the current manager at the time of the closed won opportunity. This is a pretty ugly solution, but for sake of simplicity we'll stick with it for now.

A cleaner solution would be to use Opportunity Teams since the OT will become locked after the opportunity is won. Since OTs are manually assigned, we would then need to auto-assign OTs using a trigger. This seemed to be the best solution until we gathered further requirements from stakeholders and realized we needed to lock this earlier in the sales process since the bulk of our nurturing happens well before the opportunity becomes closed won.

Ultimately, we decided to take the shortcut/first solution by capturing the manager name at the time of a stage change and using it as our "truth" field for sale counting. Would be a little nicer to use OTs because of the fact that the managers could report using the option "My teams opportunities", but oh well...

If anyone has faced a similar challenge and have an interesting solution, let me know. Thanks!